# Can I access HDFS files from Custom web application

Tags: php, python-3.x, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I have a requirement that I need to set up hadoop to save files not just text files it can be image video pdf. And there will be a web application from where user can add files and access files whenever its needed.

Can it Possible to implement ? also the web application will need to develop by me. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is written in Java, this is easily possible using the DFS Client libraries which can read and write files in HDFS in a very similar way to a standard filesystem. Basically can open an input or output stream and read whatever data you want.

If you are planning to use python to build the web application, then you could look at webHDFS, which provides a HTTP based API to put and get files from HDFS.

Comment: Thank you, sir, Can it possible in PHP?

Comment: If PHP can make calls to other webservices over HTTP then you should be able to use webHDFS. I don't have any experience with PHP myself, but I would imagine it is possible.